# The use of "to butt in"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is using "[to butt in](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/butt-in)" acceptable in a formal conversation such as business meeting in order to add something or to make a correction by speaking shortly while someone is talking?

Or can we say it means "I will say something now and I want to keep on talking"?

For example:

> Can I butt in here please

Also can "to come in"  be used in this context? Are they synonyms? Which one sounds better?

Comment: Since the meaning of  "butt" in the phrasal verb "butt in" is "hit or push against something or someone with your head", I don't think anyone would ever ask for permission to butt in. I may be mistaken, though, being a learner myself.

Comment: @Rompey -- "Can I butt in?" and "May I butt in?" are both common in American English.  On the other hand, "Can I butt in here, please?" and "May I butt in here, please?" are **not** common in my experience.

Comment: @Rompey - It's a way of softening the statement.  It's effectively saying, "I know this is an interruption, but if you will allow me..."

Comment: @stangdon -- Thanks awfully, I read the answers and I got it. Yet, what I'd like to know is which answer I would hear more often, "Go ahead" or "Mind your own business, will you?" In my culture and on the level of my interaction, it would be the latter, I think. If someone wanted me to join their discussion, which started in my absence, I'd be invited.

Comment: @Rompey - It depends a lot on context.  Probably in American culture, the response will be "Go ahead", but they may only say that because it would even more rude and blunt to turn you down.

Comment: @stangdon -- Re the cultures: well, let us agree to disagree, shall we? When in Rome, everyone supposed to do as the Romans do, be this Rome in Moscow or in Washington, DC. Thanks again for most useful comments.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly common and acceptable to use "butt in".  It is simply a more colloquial way of saying to [interject](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+interject).

The phrase is commonly used in business meetings and normal conversation.

It does not necessarily mean that the speaker wishes to take over the conversation and keep on talking, as you suggest in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Appropriateness of language can be somewhat subjective, but personally I wouldn't use *butt in* in a formal conversation unless I had already established a level of familiarity with the other participants in the meeting. With *butt in*, there's an element of taking part in the conversation without being invited, which could be perceived as rude.

If I did feel the necessity to say my piece while somebody else is speaking, I might say:

> - If I could interrupt...
> - If I could also add...

...or similar.

Of course, it is possible to offset the brashness of *butt in* by qualifying it with a certain amount of humility, e.g.

> - Sorry to butt in, but....

Comment: I like your suggestion to begin with "Sorry", but I'm curious why you think "If I could interrupt..." would be more polite than "If I may butt in..." (I'd regard both versions pretty much equivalent insofar as politeness goes.)

Comment: @J.R. - As I said, degrees of politeness can be quite subjective depending on a number of factors - country of origin being a large one. For example, in my experience, the term *to butt in* seems to be far more acceptable in American English than in BrE. But for me, *If I could interrupt* carries more of a sense of acknowledgement of the interruption, whereas *Can I butt in here please* seems more forward, with a sense of *I'm going to say my piece, regardless of the answer*.

Answer (score 1):

"Can I butt in here, please?"  has self-contradictory levels of politeness.

The phrase "butt in" honestly acknowledges that interrupting is (at least slightly) rude.  The "Can I <do something>, please?" is [obsequious](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/obsequious).

"Can I butt in here?" or "May I butt in here?" is more natural, to my (American) ear.  It has the politeness of "May I <do something>?", without the redundancy of the extra "please?"  It is both more polite and more effective than just interrupting, because it gives the person(s) being interrupted a chance to re-orient their attention before the interrupter makes their actual point.  It is also more polite because it acknowledges that the interruption is somewhat rude, and at least pretends to ask permission for the interruption.

"May I <do something>?" is slightly more polite than "Can I <do something>?"

But keep in mind that if it would be socially unacceptable to interrupt in that situation, starting the interruption with "May I butt in?" does not make the interruption acceptable.